# MVC 5 JQ grid not loading the data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid-asp.net

i written below piece of code for loading the JQ grid from the controller but Grid is not loading with any value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(this.document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#loadLogFile").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/Getresult',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mType: 'GET',
        colName: ['Log', 'Name'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Log', index: 'Log', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
              { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 20, stype: 'text' }
        ],
        gridview: true,
        loadonce: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        viewrecords: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        height: 'auto',
        width: '100%',
        autowidth: true,        
        caption: "Log File Grid"
    });
    jQuery("#pager").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
   { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
});
```

below is the C# code

```
[HttpGet]  
    public JsonResult Getresult()
    {
      //  string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\logs");

        Logfile log = new Logfile();
        log.Log = "Test";
        log.Name = "Test";
        Logfile log1 = new Logfile();
        log1.Log = "Test1";
        log1.Name = "Test1";
        List<Logfile> lLog = new List<Logfile>();
        lLog.Add(log);
        lLog.Add(log1);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lLog);

        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Not sure where is the coding is going wrong below are the JS and CSS files whic are called in the Layout page

```
    <link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the error? On the client fire F-12 (if using Chrome or IE) and then take a look at the error message that will help you find out what is going on. The order of the load of this files is also very important. Post an entire render of the client code (the grid and include scripts portion)

Comment: Hi Its not showing any error data is not loading on the grid no JS or Grid error

Comment: Ok, if you debug your GetResult method do you get data back to the page? When you have your Developer Tools open what happens after you hit the debugger statement that you have right before yout JqGrid definition?

Comment: JQ grid hits the controller method and i am returning the Json result to jq grid. but on the jqgrid it show no record to view. I am not getting any error on the JS and not sure to make out what is happening on the data which is returned by the controller. 
If possible you can take out the above code and try in your VS let me know if it works

Comment: I just followed the HTML File section on this link and got a grid on screen http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid with no data, so if you have the proper wiring it should be up and running. The sample assumes some JQuery version but as long as you understand what's needed you should be able to see the grid on screen. Too bad I can't attach my example folder so you can test it but it is just what's on the HTML File section of the link. Try to fix what's missing in there (including the CSS file)